# CoffeeScript alternative syntax for a while loop

Tags: coffeescript

I have this function written in CoffeeScript that I feel should be better written:

```
addCSS = (files) ->
  i = files.length - 1

  while i >= 0
    $("<link/>",
        rel: "stylesheet"
        href: files[i]
    ).appendTo $("head")
    i--
  return
```

The `files` arg is just an array of file paths.

Is there a more succinct/cleaner way to write this in CoffeeScript?

Comment: there is a `for f in files` syntax in coffescript, which is probably what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple

```
addCSS = (files) ->
  for file in files
    $("<link/>",
        rel: "stylesheet"
        href: file
    ).appendTo $("head")
```

(no need for return either, although it does prevent coffee from returning a bunch of stuff)

In case you are wondering, because of the horrible behavior of JS with `for ... in` loop, it is compiled as

```
for (_i = 0, _len = files.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    file = files[_i];
    // ...
}
```

### Edit

I realize just now that you are reversing the array, so it would be

```
for file in files by -1
```

(supported since 1.5.0)

compiles as `for (_i = files.length - 1; _i >= 0; _i += -1) {`

Comment: Thanks! That is cleaner. Returning a bunch of stuff like what?

Comment: by default coffee returns the result from the last line. If that line is a loop, it will create an array, gather the result of the last line of the loop, and return that array. not a big deal, but possibly a waste of memory and time

Comment: @eComEvo: If you want to avoid all that extra work you can throw a `return` at the end of your function to explicitly return nothing at all.

Comment: Yeah, I went back to doing this. I haven't fully groked the Coffee syntax, so thanks for the pointers! :)